# ting to Generic stack implementation in C with void pointers

Tags: c, stack, void-pointers

Trying to implement a simple generic stack I went trough a bunch of stack overflows and segmentation faults I wrote this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define nullptr (void *)0

struct S {
    void *content;
    struct S *next;
};
typedef struct S Stack;
Stack *createStack() {
    Stack *tmp = (Stack *) malloc(sizeof(Stack));

    tmp->content = nullptr;
    tmp->next    = nullptr;

    return tmp;
}

Stack *pushStack(Stack *ptr, void *content) {
    Stack *newStr = createStack();
    newStr->content = content;
    newStr->next = ptr;
    ptr = newStr;
    return (ptr);
}

Stack *popStack(Stack *ptr, void *value) {
    Stack *toDelete = ptr;
    value = ptr->content;
    ptr = ptr->next;
    free(toDelete);
    return (ptr);
}

Stack *stackHandle = nullptr;

void printStack(Stack *ptr) {
    int *element;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i <= 20; i++) {
        ptr = popStack(ptr, element);
        printf("%d ", *element);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    stackHandle = createStack();
    int i;
    for(i=0; i <= 21; i++) {
        stackHandle = pushStack(stackHandle, &i);
    }
    printStack(stackHandle);
}
```

Everything works but it fails to restore my int from the void pointer...
Analyzing other implementations I'm still not understanding why mine is not working.
Here I am expecting to see `21` i times but I am getting instead

`0 8240 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056 842539056`

For every value of i bigger than 20 and a beautiful segmentation fault if i is below 20

Comment: Don't define your own null pointer symbol, use the standard `NULL`. While your macro is the most common for `NULL`, it's not portable and it's also not something readers of your code will expect to see. Don't redefine what's already exists.

Comment: As for your problem, all nodes in your stack will have its data pointer point to the very same variable. It should have been very obvious if you stepped through the code in a debugger.

Comment: In addition, `nullptr` would collide with C++ in case the code gets ported.

Comment: You have to allocate space to store the `int` in the  `content`. And also store the size of the data stored.

Comment: You also need to search for and read about *emulating call by reference in c*. Because right now your `popStack` function doesn't do what you think it does. And that will lead to *undefined behavior* when you dereference `element` in the `printStack` function.

Comment: @J.Piquard Yes, I have seen this approach in some implementations, but why? I do not want to store the `int` in the `content`, I want just to store a pointer...

Comment: @J.Piquard is right - you have to allocate memory for your int value. Instead of `pushStack(stackHandle, &i)` use `int* pi = new int; *pi = i; pushStack(stackHandle, pi);`

Comment: @Zhigalin, but storing a pointer is a non-sense if it is the same value for all created nodes `&i` (address of a local variable). Also, if the size is not stored, that mean you are assuming data are always `int *`and why need to use a `void *` instead of `int`.

Comment: @J.Piquard it clearly is not a real life task, this is why it's so odd.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually allocating any space to hold actual data, you are just allocating room for pointers that point elsewhere. That's not a very useful ADT.

What I would do instead is to create a stack that holds hard-copies of the data:

```
typedef struct S {
    void*     data;
    size_t    size;
    struct S* next;
} Stack;
```

The functions would then have to be changed:

```
Stack *pushStack(Stack *ptr, void *data, size_t size);
Stack *popStack(Stack *ptr, void *data, size_t* size); // return data and size
```

You would instead create an item like this:

```
Stack *createStack (void* data, size_t size) {
    Stack *tmp = malloc(sizeof(Stack));

    tmp->data = malloc(size);
    memcpy(tmp->data, data, size);
    tmp->size = size;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    return tmp;
}
```

Once you have changed the design to something like the above, you can start worrying about weeding out the bugs.

Comment: Ok, but if I do not want to `memcpy`, why I can't just store pointers?

Comment: @Zhigalin Because pointers are not data. Suppose the caller passes a pointer to a local variable to your stack, then the function where that variable was allocated goes out of scope. The stack would point at garbage. When writing container classes like this, they should always work with hard-copies of data unless you have some very special case.

Comment: @Zhigalin In your specific example, because all pointers are pointing to the exact same memory.

Answer (score 2):

in this code:

```
for(i=0; i <= 21; i++) {
    stackHandle = pushStack(stackHandle, &i);
}
```

you are pushing the address (not the value) of the variable "i" 21 times. When you did the pop, you will retrieve this address and when you print it, you probably attain 22 (the current value of "i").

Comment: Yeah, I know... But I am not getting "variable "i" 21 times", I am getting something totally senseless!

Answer (score 1):

You get some strange values because your `ptr->content` point on value that out of the scope. You should allocate memory for your content value.
Try this:

```
    for(i=0; i <= 21; i++) {
        int* pi = new int;
        *pi = i;
        stackHandle = pushStack(stackHandle, pi);
    }
```

**UPDATED:**
Below is the corrected source code (I tested it and it work):

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define nullptr NULL;

   struct S {
     void *content;
     struct S *next;
   };
   typedef struct S Stack;
   Stack *createStack() {
      Stack *tmp = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));

       tmp->content = nullptr;
       tmp->next = nullptr;

       return tmp;
   }

   Stack *pushStack(Stack *ptr, void *content) {
      Stack *newStr = createStack();
      newStr->content = content;
      newStr->next = ptr;
      ptr = newStr;
      return (ptr);
    }
    // parameter value is of type (void**) !!!
    Stack *popStack(Stack *ptr, void **value) {
       Stack *toDelete = ptr;

       // In such a way we can return 'content' from the function.
       // 'content' is a pointer and to return it from the function
       // we should dereference pointer to a pointer 'value'
       *value = (ptr->content); 

       ptr = ptr->next;
       free(toDelete);
      return (ptr);
   }

   Stack *stackHandle = nullptr;

   void printStack(Stack *ptr) {
       int *element;
       int i;
       for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
          ptr = popStack(ptr, (void**)&element); // pointer to apointer !!!
          if (element) {
             printf("%d ", *element);
             // deallocate memory and escape memory leaks !!!
             delete(element);
          }
       }
       printf("\n");
  }

  int main() {
     stackHandle = createStack();
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i <= 21; i++) {
         int* pi = new int(i); // allocate memory !!!
         stackHandle = pushStack(stackHandle, pi);
     }
     printStack(stackHandle);
 }
```

***Key fixes.***

1. we allocate memory for i as `int* pi = new int(i);`
2. and type of *value* parameter of the *popStack* function is changed from (void*) to (void**).

Comment: @Zhigalin, please confirm where the error occurs with your debugger.

Comment: I update my answer with fixed source code. This code compiles and outputs: *21 22 20 ... 4 3 2 1* as expected